# React Native transform in styled-components

Tags: react-native, styled-components

Am I able to use transform in styled-components in React Native?

I define the styled component like this:

```
const StyledAnimatedView = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(styled.View<
    ViewProps
  >`
    transform: translateY(-100);
`);
```

but it throws me an error when component mounts:

> Error: Failed to parse declaration "transform: translateY(-100)"

I know it is possible in web but maybe not in React Native?

Answer (score 1):

```
transform: translateY(-100px);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that "px" is necessary in most cases when you are using react native. btw, you can use [props](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props).

```
styled.View<ViewProps>`
    transform: translateY(${props => props.translateY});
`);


<StyledAnimatedView translateY={'-100px'}/>
```